# Test Class Failure : DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Unique_Record_ID__c duplicates value on record with id:

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, failing-tests

I am facing an issue with a test class. Getting the following error

> (System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0xuxuxuxuu..; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Unique_Record_ID__c duplicates value on record with id: a0xuxuxuxuu.. []
>   )

Snippet of the code:

```
    if(CPL3.Max_Width_mm__c==CPL3.Width_Met_Open__c|| CPL3.Max_Width__c== CPL3.Wide_Stamp_Metric__c)
            { 

      CPL3.Currency__c = 'USD';
        update CPL3; 

        CPL3.Currency__c = 'GBP';
        update CPL3; 

        CPL3.Currency__c = 'CAD';
        update CPL3 ; 
            }   
        Product2 pro4 = new Product2();
        pro4.name='Test';
        pro4.Family = 'Fabric';
        insert pro4;

        Customer_s_Price_List__c CPL4 = new Customer_s_Price_List__c();
        CPL4.Name = 'Test';
        CPL4.Currency__c = 'EUR';
        CPL4.Account__c = acc.Id;
        CPL4.Cost_by__c = 'Square Yards';
        CPL4.Product_Description__c = pro4.Id;
        CPL4.Product_Type__c = 'Fabric'; 
        CPL4.System_Of_Measurement__c = 'Metric System';
        CPL4.Cost_by__c= '12';

        CPL4.Price_of__c= NULL;
        CPL4.Wide_Imperial__c= '12';
        CPL4.Width__c = '12';
        CPL4.Width_Imp_Open__c = 0;

        CPL4.Wide_Imperial__c = '1';

        insert CPL4;          
        CPL4.Currency__c = 'USD';
        upsert CPL4;
```

---- Error is coming at this line.

```
        CPL4.Currency__c = 'GBP';
        upsert CPL4; 

        CPL4.Currency__c = 'CAD';

        upsert CPL4; 


        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Comment: what value are you setting in the field Unique_Record_ID__c? It looks like, that is a unique field and duplicate records are getting inserted

Comment: I am setting no values . Still searching what is causing the same.

Comment: It looks like a custom field with unique property on it. So in your test class you definitely would have to set value for that field